# How to render HTML on Swift with clickable link?

Tags: html, swift, webview, render

I am trying to do it with this code:

```
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: contentLabel.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)
```

It renders properly as HTML, but link is not working.

What am I doing wrong?